# SSL peer not authenticated Exception for Firebase real time database

Tags: spring, firebase, spring-mvc, firebase-realtime-database

We are trying to post some data to firebase real time database and for some reason some of the request im getting peer not authenticated and some of the request are working properly . There is no pattern but some random request are failing.

Please note there is no server restart or any change .

Randomly some request im getting SSL peer not authenticated error.

Please help to resolve this issue.

success request :

```
2018/04/05 18:16:25,150- FlowContext-161 INFO   - serviceAccount done
2018/04/05 18:16:25,151- FlowContext-161 INFO   - FirebaseInvoker | postToFireBase | line No :49 | Firebase calledjava.io.FileInputStream@40d108c9 |  | 
2018/04/05 18:16:25,152- FlowContext-161 INFO   - FirebaseInvoker | postToFireBase | line No :60 | Authenticating Using Google Credentials |  | 
2018/04/05 18:16:25,152- FlowContext-161 INFO   - FirebaseInvoker | postToFireBase | line No :62 | Authentication Done |  | 
2018/04/05 18:16:25,227- FlowContext-161 INFO   - HttpClientUtil | postRequest[52] |  |
2018/04/05 18:16:25,227- FlowContext-161 INFO   - HttpClientUtil | postRequest[53] |  | Inside PostRequest Method . Input data >> Request Properties = {Content-Type=text/plain}         Header data =null       Request Data =          Cert =null      is-Via-Proxy?? = true
2018/04/05 18:16:25,228- FlowContext-161 INFO   - HttpClientUtil | postRequest[76] |  |  Adding Custom HostNameVerifier.
2018/04/05 18:16:25,228- FlowContext-161 INFO   - HttpClientUtil | getConnection[142] |  | Opening Connection via proxy server.
2018/04/05 18:16:25,228- FlowContext-161 INFO   - HttpClientUtil | postRequest[81] |  | Connection Opened . Request Method : DELETE
2018/04/05 18:16:25,228- FlowContext-161 INFO   - HttpClientUtil | postRequest[95] |  | Setting Request Header values
2018/04/05 18:16:25,228- FlowContext-161 INFO   - HttpClientUtil | postRequest[98] |  | Key : Content-Type Value : text/plain
2018/04/05 18:16:26,067- FlowContext-161 INFO   - Response Code:::200
2018/04/05 18:16:26,068- FlowContext-161 INFO   - HttpClientUtil | readResponse[168] |  | Response Message Received : null
2018/04/05 18:16:26,068- FlowContext-161 INFO   - Response Code:::200
2018/04/05 18:16:26,068- FlowContext-161 INFO   - HttpClientUtil | postRequest[125] |  |  Response Received : null
2018/04/05 18:16:26,068- FlowContext-161 INFO   - FirebaseInvoker | postToFireBase[81] |  | Response : null
2018/04/05 18:16:26,069- FlowContext-161 INFO   - APIResponseBuilder | buildsellerModeResp | line No :2234 | Preparing build sellerMode Response Message. |  | 
2018/04/05 18:16:26,069- FlowContext-161 INFO   - APIResponseBuilder | buildsellerModeResp | line No :2256 | Response Message >> : {"errorCode":0,"reqRefNo":"PAYLAH3822E7684F314364A45D43D2"} |  |
```

Failure reuqest :

```
2018/04/05 18:19:26,247- FlowContext-167 INFO   - serviceAccount done
2018/04/05 18:19:26,247- FlowContext-167 INFO   - FirebaseInvoker | postToFireBase | line No :49 | Firebase calledjava.io.FileInputStream@25c89678 |  | 
2018/04/05 18:19:26,249- FlowContext-167 INFO   - FirebaseInvoker | postToFireBase | line No :60 | Authenticating Using Google Credentials |  | 
2018/04/05 18:19:26,249- FlowContext-167 INFO   - FirebaseInvoker | postToFireBase | line No :62 | Authentication Done |  | 
2018/04/05 18:19:26,284- FlowContext-167 INFO   - FirebaseInvoker | postToFireBase | line No :87 | Firebase Posting started Step 5javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:399)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:167)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.layerProtocol(AbstractPoolEntry.java:275)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.layerProtocol(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:138)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:704)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:421)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
        at com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest.execute(ApacheHttpRequest.java:67)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the SSL cert has expired and i downloaded and added to server jks and started working.